# Understanding a C exception program

Tags: c, exception

I am working on this [example](http://www.di.unipi.it/~nids/docs/longjump_try_trow_catch.html) to try understand functions `longjmp` and `setjmp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

#define TRY do{ jmp_buf ex_buf__; if( !setjmp(ex_buf__) ){
#define CATCH } else {
#define ETRY } }while(0)
#define THROW longjmp(ex_buf__, 1)

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   TRY
   {
      printf("In Try Statement\n");
      THROW;
      printf("I do not appear\n");
   }
   CATCH
   {
      printf("Got Exception!\n");
   }
   ETRY;

   return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the `#define`s at the beginning of the code:

1- What is the `ex_buf__`?

2- In the page from which I took this example, it is said:

> When the THROW statement is executed it simply calls the longjmp
>   function with the second parameter equals to 1 (or anything not 0).

Why is it possible to take any value not 0?

Comment: what compiler? essentially its doing a goto.

Comment: `ex_buf__` is a reference to something in some code that you didn't show us.

Comment: `ex_buf__` is just a variable name it can be anything.

Comment: @DanielA.White the compiler they use in the example is gcc

Comment: @RobertHarvey its in the macro for `TRY`.

Comment: `ex_buf__` is local variable name. You should write those macros out, to better understand what is happening.

Comment: @hyde when writing out the macros: shall I replace ex_buf__ by something?

Comment: Only do the four substitutions defined by the four defines. None of them changes ex_buf__...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Lohan is a nasty autocorrect-generated typo, you wouldn't want to get acquainted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#define` directive is a [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) directive. It's used to define macros used by the preprocessor to replace their invocation in other paces in the code.

For example, you have the following macro

```
#define TRY do{ jmp_buf ex_buf__; if( !setjmp(ex_buf__) ){
```

Whenever the preprocessor sees `TRY` elsewhere in the code, it's replaced by its contents. So the line

```
TRY
```

becomes

```
do{ jmp_buf ex_buf__; if( !setjmp(ex_buf__) ){
```

---

As for your other questions, the `ex_buf__` is simply a variable declared (and defined) inside the loop created by the `TRY` macro expansion. It's scope is inside the loop, and all nested scopes inside the loop.

For the last question, see in the `TRY` macro the call to `setjmp`? It is part of a conditional statement in an `if` statement. Note the exclamation mark `!` before the function call? That means the returned value from the function is negated, that is a zero value becomes one, and anything non-zero becomes zero. The `longjmp` function causes the code to unconditionally jump to the `setjmp` call, and makes `setjmp` return the value of the second argument to `longjmp`. Since the second argument to `longjmp` is non-zero, the expression `!setjmp(...)` will be zero, and the code jumps to the `else` part of the `if` statement, which is the `CATCH` part of the try-catch emulation.

Comment: So `ex_buf__` has local scope?

Answer (score 2):

After preprocessing, your code becomes:

```
int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   do{
       jmp_buf ex_buf__;
       if( !setjmp(ex_buf__) )
       {
          printf("In Try Statement\n");
          longjmp(ex_buf__, 1);
          printf("I do not appear\n");
       }
       else
       {
           printf("Got Exception!\n");
       }
   }while(0);

   return 0;
}
```

jmp_buf and longjmp are declared in setjmp.h.

Answer (score 1):

`ex_buf__` is a `jmp_buf` that is declared in the `TRY` macro.  `longjmp` will only jump on non-0 values kinda like an if statement.

Comment: The way the macros are written seems to suggest that you can only THROW in a TRY block (since `ex_buf` is defined in the TRY macro).  Of what use is that?  What happens if you do it twice?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i have no clue - its a clever hack as it is as it doesn't cause the cpu to accumulate the stack.

Comment: @RobertHarvey do what twice?

Comment: THROW twice, or TRY twice.  I'm beginning to see why so many think preprocessor macros are evil.  Maybe not evil, but certainly oversimplified.

Comment: `THROW` should be safe as the execution has moved on to a different address. `TRY` might cause some things because it will redeclare `ex_buf__`.

Comment: if `THROW` is called by a `THROW` I'm guessing it enters a non-ending loop.